# EC2 deployment of golang app using CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a simple golang webserver to EC2 using CodeDeploy.  Deployment fails with following error `{\"error_code\":6,\"script_name\":\"scripts/start.sh\",\"message\":\"Script at specified location: scripts/start.sh failed to close STDOUT\"`. CodeDeploy related files:

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0

os: linux

files:
  - source: /main.go
    destination: /app/
  - source: /index.html
    destination: /app/
  - source: /config.json
    destination: /app/
  - source: /webserver.log
    destination: /app/

hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/cleanup.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/build.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start.sh
      timeout: 180
      runas: root
```

scripts/cleanup.sh

```
sudo rm /app -rf
sudo mkdir /app
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /app

sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y golang
```

scripts/build.sh

```
go build -o /app/webserver /app/main.go
```

scripts/start.sh

```
/app/webserver &
```

I imagine it's related to how I start the server, but I'm no good with Linux intricacies so more detailed explanation would be highly appreciated.

Full webserver source code can be found in [github](https://github.com/vikusku/webserver).

Answer (score 5):

I think it's related to  `stdout, stderr, and stdin`:

Add below string before &

```
/dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null
```

[The source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-long-running-processes)

Comment: Hi, 
I'm getting the STDOUT error on my application_start.sh. Where would you recommend adding this line in my code?

```#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ec2-user
npm run start&```

Comment: before `&` and after `start` I think.

Comment: You've just helped me finish my 8 day quest to completing my first Code Commit to EC2 instance. Thanks a lot for helping!